# SDK path amnesia

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am using the free version of Mono For Android on Win 7 x64. Everything worked fine until I upgraded Mono to the latest version, then run Start Android Emulator Manager from VS' Tools menu and updated everything there. Next I've applied the latest Windows Update patches (today) and now mono won't find SDK images anymore. Not sure which of these steps caused the problem, I assume the latest.

### Here is the exception I get upon trying to run an application and clicking on Start emulator image:

---

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: path1

```
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Utils.FilePath.Combine(String[] paths)

   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidSdk..ctor(FilePath androidPath, FilePath javaBinPath)

   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidSdk.get_Sdk()

   at MonoDroid.Adb.EnsureAdbExists()

   at MonoDroid.Adb.EnsureServerRunning()

   at MonoDroid.Adb.GetDevices()

   at Novell.MonoDroidVS.DeviceChooser.<PopulateDevices>b__0()
```

---

### OK

I get the same exception when invoking Start Android Emulator Manager from VS' Tools menu.

I've checked the settings and nothing was changed - Android SDK location points to correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I somehow uninstalled Android SDK platform tools. Once reinstalled everything works again.
Now, it would be nice to have a better error message mentioning the source of the problem...